# Проблема с прокручиванием большого количества элементов в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть ListView в котором есть 1000 элементов и при быстрой прокрутке списка возникает эффект как у колеса машины, сначала в одну сторону прокрутка идет , а потом обратно, хотя по факту он в нужную сторону крутится, каким образом можно избавиться от этого эффекта? Возможно для большого количества элементов в списке нужен другой адаптер ?

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "ContactListAdapter";

    ArrayList<Contact> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    private ViewHolder preHolder;
    private ViewHolder secondHold;


    public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ContactList contactList) {
        this.context = context;
        list = contactList;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<ContactCaling> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        private View rootView;
        private TextView tvName;
        private TextView tvInitials;
        private ImageView ivAvatart;
        private ImageView ivStatus;

        private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutParent;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutMain;
        private RelativeLayout onlineButtonContainer;
        private RelativeLayout timeoutButtonContainer;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout_exit_buuton_conteiner;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout_icon_phone;
        private String contactName;
        private boolean isShow;

        private ContactCaling contactCaling;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rootView = convertView;

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            holder.rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_contact_list_item, null);


            holder.tvName = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_name);
            holder.tvInitials = (TextView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_contact_initials);
            holder.ivAvatart = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_contact_avatar);
            holder.ivStatus = (ImageView) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_status);
            holder.relativeLayoutParent = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_parent);
            holder.relativeLayoutMain = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_main);
            holder.onlineButtonContainer = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_call_button_container);
            holder.relativeLayout_icon_phone = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_icon_phone);
            holder.timeoutButtonContainer = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_call_busy_button_container);
            holder.relativeLayout_exit_buuton_conteiner = (RelativeLayout) holder.rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_exit_buuton_conteiner);

            /**-------------Item listener---------------**/


            holder.relativeLayoutParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (preHolder == null || (secondHold != null && secondHold.equals(holder))) {
                        if (MyApplication.isOnline()) {
                            int buttonTranslation = -holder.onlineButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width + 2;

                            holder.onlineButtonContainer
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                            secondHold = null;
                        } else {
                            int buttonTranslation = -holder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width + 2;

                            holder.timeoutButtonContainer
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(buttonTranslation)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                            secondHold = null;
                        }

                    }

                    if (preHolder != null) {

                        if (MyApplication.isOnline()) {
                            int translate = preHolder.onlineButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width;
                            preHolder.relativeLayoutMain
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(0)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                            preHolder.onlineButtonContainer
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(translate)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                        } else {
                            int translate = preHolder.timeoutButtonContainer.getLayoutParams().width;
                            preHolder.relativeLayoutMain
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(0)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                            preHolder.timeoutButtonContainer
                                    .animate()
                                    .translationX(translate)
                                    .setDuration(350);
                        }

                    }

                    if (preHolder != null) {
                        preHolder = null;
                    } else {
                        preHolder = holder;
                    }
                    secondHold = holder;
                }

            });


            holder.isShow = false;
            holder.rootView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.contact = (Contact) getItem(position);
        holder.contactName = holder.contact.getDisplayName();

        holder.tvName.setText(holder.contactName);
        setIcons(position, holder);

        return holder.rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно сделать так, что бы частота обновления экрана была различна с частотой прокручивания элементов списка. 
Наверно можно уменьшить скорость скрола `ListView`

```
listView.setFriction(ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction() * FRICTION_SCALE_FACTOR)
```